# Spring JMS Testing and Transactional Rollback

Tags: spring, junit, jms

I have a test harness using Spring's `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` (which automatically rolls back DB updates at the end of each JUnit test).  Now I want to test my Spring-based JMS code:

1. Some DB item is created
2. A JMS message is sent to do something
3. The MDP picks up the message and does something else in the DB

What is actually happening in the Test is the following:

1. Spring begins the transaction (tx1) on thread 1
2. The DB item is created in the tx1 context
3. The JMS message is sent
4. Transction tx1 is rolled back and thread 1 exits
5. Thread 2 spins up the MDP, begins transaction tx2, reads the message, and does DB work
6. Thread 2 commits tx2, as its not spun up by the test harness, and exits

What I want to have happen is for tx1 and tx2 to both be controlled by `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` so I get the automatic rollback.  Even better would be if they could share the same overall transactional context; right now, if something is saved in tx1, even if Thread 1 hasn't rolled back that tx, tx2 doesn't see the DB changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a transaction manager that supports XA, and is thus able to do a two-phase commit on the database and the JMS engine. There are several such transaction managers (Bitronix, Atomikos, etc.) freely available.

If you already use such a transaction manager (because your app runs in an application server providing it), but you don't want to configure something as heavy just for the unit tests, then implement two unit tests

- one where the JMS part is mocked up (to test the DB item creation only),
- and one where only the JMS message handling is tested

Note that without XA, you'll probably have to handle bizarre situations where the JMS message is handled whereas the first transaction is not committed yet, or where the database transaction is comitted but the sending of the message fails.